# grafana kafka alert when consumergroup value(sum) stays same for X min

Tags: apache-kafka, grafana, grafana-alerts

Im using kafka general dashboard for grafana
https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/11962-kafka-metrics/
prometheus datasource

I have a panel for consumer lag
query: sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag) by (consumergroup)
alert query for specific consumer group :
sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup="CONSUMER_GRP_NAME"}) by (consumergroup)

now I need a grafana alert when the sum (count) is same for X min

Scenario : For CONSUMER_GRP_NAME if the count is 1500(example) stayed same for X min . My goal is to identify when its not getting processed for X min I need an alert

Answer (score 0):

EG:

```
sum_over_time(kafka_consumergroup_group_sum_lag{group=~"(Q..-000)\\..*", group!~".*Local"}[120m])
```

Answer (score 0):

We have victoria metrics for query type that is listed as below:

```
kafka_consumergroup_group_max_lag{group!~"((KMOffsetCache|STAGIN).+)",group!~".+_local",group!~".*STAGING.*",group!~"STATSGEOLOCATE|REST-MONGO-GROUP-1|WHEREABOUTS-PROD|STATSCHECKOUTCONV_V2_GREEN"}

kafka_consumergroup_group_max_lag{group=~"STATSGEOLOCATE|REST-MONGO-GROUP-1|WHEREABOUTS-PROD|STATSCHECKOUTCONV_V2_GREEN"}
```

Now, we want the consumergroup name in the summary/message if we receive alert, but this seems that it is not working.

Alert triggered for Kafka consumer group: `{{ .Labels.group }}`

Is there any way to get the name?